# Is there a better way to see if a field in a Lua table exists if it is initialized with false

Tags: lua, lua-table

So as the title suggests. Consider this source:

```
A = {}
A.T = true
A.F = false
A.N = 123
A.S = "ASDF"
A.E = ""

for k,v in pairs(A) do
  local Ex = "" 
  if(A[k]) then Ex = "YES"
  else Ex = "NO"
  end
  print(k,v,Ex)
end
```

Which prints ( The order is different because it's `pairs` ):

```
T       true    YES
F       false   NO
S       ASDF    YES
N       123     YES
E               YES
```

As you see here the `A.F = false` and the `if` statement says it not exists.
Is there any better way to see if the `F` exists as a field in the table despite being a boolean with a `false` value written in it better than `pairs` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't check for false-y-ness. Check for "is nil".

So, don't do `if X then`. Do `if X ~= nil then`.